# Android App Build fails with multiple modules with Aidl files (Program type already present)

Tags: android, module, aidl

I created two modules A(Client) and B(Server) and defined AIDL files to communicate among them. 
Now I want to use both the modules in my App.

When I include both of them in my App it runs fine from Android Studio but when I try to build Apk it Fails..

```
Getting this error "Program type already present: my.package.BuildConfig"
```

Here the Buildconfig files are from the 2 modules A and B

Since the AIDL has to be same in both the modules and also the package has to be the same, it will generate the same files in Both the modules.

How do I build in this case by ignoring the duplicate files ? 
Any pointer to solve this ?

Comment: Do both modules share the same base name space? They shoukd be different i.e. `my.package.client` & `my.package.server`.  If the aidl files need to be used by both have them in a third separate lib that both these libs depend on

Comment: Package change looks the only solution. I was under impression that the package name should be same for the AIDL files to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Mark Keen**  suggested We can't have the same package name in both client and server module and include them in App.

I have changed one of them and able to build now.

Thanks @Mark Keen for the suggestion.